# What's wrong with this jQuery AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

My jQuery.ajax() function doesn't work.. 
I would like to display JSON data from a server.. The request succeeds, I found out via Firebug. When i delete *function(data) {* in the "success"-tag the alert fires, when the function stays, it does not..
By the way: the request always succeeds, also when username and password are wrong, how could that be? But when I delete the *xhr.setRequestHeader()* method Firebug shows that the call ends up with "unauthorized" because of the basic authentication the server needs..

Any suggestions to solve this? Thanks in advance!

My javascript "gadget.js"

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8387/nscalemc/rest/mon/resourcestatus.json",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        var base64 = btoa('admin' + ":" + 'admin');
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic" + base64);
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $(data.groupStatus).each(function() {
            $("body").append("<p>ID: " + this.id + "</p>");
        });
        alert("success!");
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    alert("done!");
    $(data.groupStatus).each(function() {
        $("body").append("<p>ID: " + this.id + "</p>");
    });
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert("fail - " + textStatus);
});​
```

Here's my JSON

```
{
    "groupStatus": [
        {
            "id": "Application Layer Configuration-ApplicationLayer",
            "time": 1332755316976,
            "level": 0,
            "warningIds": [],
            "errorIds": []
        },
        {
            "id": "Application Layer-ApplicationLayer:nscalealinst2",
            "time": 1333431531046,
            "level": 0,
            "warningIds": [],
            "errorIds": []
        }
    ]
}
```

And finally my HTML class "gadget.html":

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Gadget</title>
    <link href="css/gadget.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/gadget.js"></script>
</body>
```

Why are my id's not displayed?

By the way: Whats the difference between *.done(function(){})* and *"success: (function(){})* ?

Comment: is the JSON file on the same domain? If not, lookup Cross-Domain Ajax. (JSONP)

Comment: do you happen to know that `success` and `done` do the same thing? and  it's redundant in your code?

Comment: Im thinking its your JSON call, since your script is working fine (see: http://jsfiddle.net/vbeSm/) - is it crossdomain as @PoweRoy asked?

Comment: okay, but why does firebug shows "200 success" status then?

Comment: @Joseph yes, i know, i've tested it this way.. i know the duplication

Comment: 200 means that the page returned successfully. what's the content? and what's the page status if auth fails? don't tell me it's also 200? if so, the success will always trigger.

Comment: no it's not, i get an "unauthorized" status then..

Comment: okay, i ll try jsonp now, it seems that this could be the solution! thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I will answer what I know: there is a note in the doc about the difference between done() and success():

> **Deprecation Notice**: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

You could use getJSON() instead of ajax() if you are working with JSON.
Hope it helps!.

Comment: I tried this before, but getJSON() doesn't support basic authentication which i need for this request